# How to avoid pop-up message on VPN connection?

Tags: macos, vpn

Apple Mac OS can display a server side configured message when you establish a vpn connection (Cisco IPSec in my case).

I want to disable this annoying popup so how can I configure the VPN configuration to just ignore this message instead of prompting me to press the ok button.

Comment: Looking for similar solution. Did you find anyway?? Please share